# How to fix ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe' upon opening jupyter notebook (anaconda3)?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I used to open it just fine, writing code and all, but after I tried importing pandas_profiling, which returned

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-1.1.1.dist-info\direct_url.json' Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

I tried the code `pip install pandas-profiling`, restarting the kernel, but it returned message that is something in the line of which the script is installed but

> "is not on PATH, and consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location".

To where I kind of forget what I did that resulted in a

> EnvironmentNotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to the target environment. environment location: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3

After that, I tried one solution from this website to just run the jupyter notebook (anaconda3) with administrator right. After I set the shortcut to run with administrator right, the app just flashed its black command windows before disappearing and not opening notebook in my browser, unlike when it worked just fine when the black windows stay there.

Then I uninstalled, tried installing it again with the newer versions of anaconda, but to no avail. So then I tried using anaconda prompt, to update any package that were deemed missing, but still no result. Then tried running jupyter notebook through it, which resulted in

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\NXHSE\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in  from notebook.notebookapp import main

File "C:\Users\NXHSE\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 43, in  from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

File "C:\Users\NXHSE\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2_*init*_.py", line 12, in  from .environment import Environment

File "C:\Users\NXHSE\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 25, in  from .defaults import BLOCK_END_STRING

File "C:\Users\NXHSE\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\defaults.py", line 3, in  from .filters import FILTERS as DEFAULT_FILTERS  # noqa: F401

File "C:\Users\NXHSE\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\filters.py", line 13, in  from markupsafe import soft_unicode

ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe' (C:\Users\NXHSE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\markupsafe_*init*_.py)

One thread suggesting to install markupsafe, but at present I haven't tried it for fearing any more complication. Can anyone help finding out what seems to be the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Fixed it for me, even outside of Docker: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72191560/importerror-cannot-import-name-soft-unicode-from-markupsafe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: cannot import name 'soft\_unicode' from 'markupsafe'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72191560/importerror-cannot-import-name-soft-unicode-from-markupsafe)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem

Try writting the following in the console "Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda 3)".

```
pip install markupsafe==2.0.1 --force-reinstall
```

You should see something like this

[image]

After this, Jupyter Notebooks launches correctly.