# Cannot launch Jupyter Notebook from Anaconda Navigator

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I want to launch Jupyter Notebook from Anaconda Navigator but I get this error code:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\MSI\miniconda3\envs\cb2030-labs-environment-windows\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "C:\Users\MSI\miniconda3\envs\cb2030-labs-environment-windows\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 43, in 
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
File "C:\Users\MSI\miniconda3\envs\cb2030-labs-environment-windows\lib\site-packages\jinja2\__init__.py", line 12, in 
from .environment import Environment
File "C:\Users\MSI\miniconda3\envs\cb2030-labs-environment-windows\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 25, in 
from .defaults import BLOCK_END_STRING
File "C:\Users\MSI\miniconda3\envs\cb2030-labs-environment-windows\lib\site-packages\jinja2\defaults.py", line 3, in 
from .filters import FILTERS as DEFAULT_FILTERS # noqa: F401
File "C:\Users\MSI\miniconda3\envs\cb2030-labs-environment-windows\lib\site-packages\jinja2\filters.py", line 13, in 
from markupsafe import soft_unicode
ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe' (C:\Users\MSI\miniconda3\envs\cb2030-labs-environment-windows\lib\site-packages\markupsafe\__init__.py)
```

I am not using the `base (root)` but another environment specific for my course.

Does anyone know why I get this error and how I can solve it? Thank you!

Comment: [This post](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyter-is-not-opening/15148?u=fomightez) is similar but it doesn't seem you have conflicting installations. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72206981/8508004) looks related and says it is because `soft_unicode` was removed from `markupsafe`. Does your root environment still launch Jupyter Notebook? If so, make sure you only change any of this in your environment. [This looks good](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73531396/8508004) but it is suggesting `pip`. Have you been mixing and matching. ...

Comment: <continued> I sort of wish there was a conda only path suggested, but I haven't found one yet. (So please update if you have any luck. It may be good to know what is compatible at least.) [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73869713/8508004) suggests just editing all(?) the instances involving `soft_unicode` to `soft_str`, I think.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74371539/8508004) has a nice command to force the re-install step if you are having issues.