# Getting ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe' for a conda environment while running `jupyter notebook`

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda, miniconda

- My conda env was working fine till today when I activated it, it showed an Import error when I ran `Jupyter Notebook` command.

  [image]
- Tried this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72191560/importerror-cannot-import-name-soft-unicode-from-markupsafe),

  - Reinstalling markupsafe didn't work
  - Thought of removing whole conda env and recreating with required libs
  - Didn't work
- Looked at this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73060545/how-to-fix-importerror-cannot-import-name-soft-unicode-from-markupsafe-upon?noredirect=1&lq=1):

  - Didn't seem to be the problem I've encountered.

  I'd appreciate any help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading to an earlier version, if you are testing

```
pip install markupsafe==2.0.1
```

Downgrade to:

```
pip install markupsafe==2.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I got this error after a fresh install and downgrading `markupsafe` did not fix it, however instead upgrading `jinja2` from `2.10.1` to `3.1.2` seemed to do the trick.

First undo the downgrade if you tried that.

```
 pip install -U markupsafe
```

Then bump jinja2

```
 pip install -U jinja2
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause with your question may stem from a dependency management conflict between two software ecosystems. According to the error message, your markupsafe was installed using pip at the path `/home/azriel-ubuntu-wsl/.local/python3.8/dist-packages/markupsafe/`. The jinja2 that depends on it was installed using apt at the path `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jinja2`. The versions of the two are not compatible. In fact, there is a version of markupsafe in the system that jinja2 correctly depends on, but the Python interpreter prioritizes the markupsafe installed by pip, leading to this issue. There are typically two solutions to this problem: (1) Use pip to uninstall markupsafe, and then reinstall it using apt, or uninstall jinja2 using apt and reinstall it using pip. (2) Use Python's imp module to customize the path and import the markupsafe from the apt path before importing jinja2. An example is as follows:

```
import imp
path = ['/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('markupsafe', path)
imp.load_module("markupsafe", fp, pathname, description)
```

Hope my diagnosis is helpful to you！