# Can't open jupyter and get an import error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, importerror

Last time I closed jupyter, there were a few files running(not sure if this had an effect on this problem) Now when trying to run it, it gives me an error. I tried running pip install markupsafe==2.0.1 in my command prompt and that didn't work. I've provided my pip and conda lists below because I believe some upgrade or installation that I did caused this. I had just installed a few things today.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "C:\Users\crist\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\Users\crist\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 44, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
  File "C:\Users\crist\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .environment import Environment
  File "C:\Users\crist\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .defaults import BLOCK_END_STRING
  File "C:\Users\crist\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\defaults.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .filters import FILTERS as DEFAULT_FILTERS  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\Users\crist\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\filters.py", line 13, in <module>
    from markupsafe import soft_unicode
ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe' (C:\Users\crist\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\markupsafe\__init__.py)
```

Conda list:

```
_anaconda_depends 2022.05 py39_0
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf 0.1.0 py39haa95532_0
absl-py 0.15.0 pypi_0 pypi
aiohttp 3.8.1 py39h2bbff1b_1
aiosignal 1.2.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
alabaster 0.7.12 pyhd3eb1b0_0
anaconda custom py39_1
anaconda-client 1.9.0 py39haa95532_0
anaconda-navigator 2.2.0 py39haa95532_0
anaconda-project 0.10.2 pyhd3eb1b0_0
anyio 3.5.0 py39haa95532_0
appdirs 1.4.4 pyhd3eb1b0_0
argon2-cffi 21.3.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
argon2-cffi-bindings 21.2.0 py39h2bbff1b_0
arrow 1.2.2 pyhd3eb1b0_0
astroid 2.6.6 py39haa95532_0
astropy 5.0.4 py39h080aedc_0
asttokens 2.0.5 pyhd3eb1b0_0
astunparse 1.6.3 pypi_0 pypi
async-timeout 4.0.1 pyhd3eb1b0_0
atomicwrites 1.4.0 py_0
attrs 21.4.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
automat 20.2.0 py_0
autopep8 1.6.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
babel 2.9.1 pyhd3eb1b0_0
backcall 0.2.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
backports 1.1 pyhd3eb1b0_0
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.4 pyhd3eb1b0_0
backports.tempfile 1.0 pyhd3eb1b0_1
backports.weakref 1.0.post1 py_1
bcrypt 3.2.0 py39h196d8e1_0
beautifulsoup4 4.11.1 py39haa95532_0
binaryornot 0.4.4 pyhd3eb1b0_1
bitarray 2.4.1 py39h2bbff1b_0
bkcharts 0.2 py39haa95532_0
black 19.10b0 py_0
blas 1.0 mkl
bleach 4.1.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
blosc 1.21.0 h19a0ad4_0
bokeh 2.4.2 py39haa95532_0
boto3 1.21.32 pyhd3eb1b0_0
botocore 1.24.32 pyhd3eb1b0_0
bottleneck 1.3.4 py39h080aedc_0
brotli 1.0.9 ha925a31_2
brotlipy 0.7.0 py39h2bbff1b_1003
bzip2 1.0.8 he774522_0
ca-certificates 2022.07.19 haa95532_0
cachetools 5.2.0 pypi_0 pypi
certifi 2022.9.24 py39haa95532_0
cffi 1.15.0 py39h2bbff1b_1
cfitsio 3.470 he774522_6
chardet 4.0.0 py39haa95532_1003
charls 2.2.0 h6c2663c_0
charset-normalizer 2.1.1 pypi_0 pypi
click 8.0.4 py39haa95532_0
cloudpickle 2.0.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
clyent 1.2.2 py39haa95532_1
colorama 0.4.4 pyhd3eb1b0_0
colorcet 2.0.6 pyhd3eb1b0_0
comtypes 1.1.10 py39haa95532_1002
conda 22.9.0 py39haa95532_0
conda-build 3.21.8 py39haa95532_2
conda-content-trust 0.1.1 pyhd3eb1b0_0
conda-env 2.6.0 haa95532_1
conda-pack 0.6.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
conda-package-handling 1.8.1 py39h8cc25b3_0
conda-repo-cli 1.0.4 pyhd3eb1b0_0
conda-token 0.3.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
conda-verify 3.4.2 py_1
console_shortcut 0.1.1 4
constantly 15.1.0 pyh2b92418_0
cookiecutter 1.7.3 pyhd3eb1b0_0
cryptography 3.4.8 py39h71e12ea_0
cssselect 1.1.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
curl 7.82.0 h2bbff1b_0
cycler 0.11.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
cython 0.29.28 py39hd77b12b_0
cytoolz 0.11.0 py39h2bbff1b_0
daal4py 2021.5.0 py39h8cb3d55_0
dal 2021.5.0 haa95532_796
dask 2022.2.1 pyhd3eb1b0_0
dask-core 2022.2.1 pyhd3eb1b0_0
dataclasses 0.8 pyh6d0b6a4_7
datashader 0.13.0 pyhd3eb1b0_1
datashape 0.5.4 py39haa95532_1
debugpy 1.5.1 py39hd77b12b_0
decorator 5.1.1 pyhd3eb1b0_0
defusedxml 0.7.1 pyhd3eb1b0_0
diff-match-patch 20200713 pyhd3eb1b0_0
dill 0.3.5.1 pypi_0 pypi
distributed 2022.2.1 pyhd3eb1b0_0
docutils 0.17.1 py39haa95532_1
entrypoints 0.4 py39haa95532_0
et_xmlfile 1.1.0 py39haa95532_0
executing 0.8.3 pyhd3eb1b0_0
filelock 3.6.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
flake8 3.9.2 pyhd3eb1b0_0
flask 1.1.2 pyhd3eb1b0_0
flatbuffers 1.12 pypi_0 pypi
fonttools 4.25.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
freetype 2.10.4 hd328e21_0
frozenlist 1.2.0 py39h2bbff1b_0
fsspec 2022.2.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
future 0.18.2 py39haa95532_1
gast 0.4.0 pypi_0 pypi
gensim 4.1.2 py39hd77b12b_0
giflib 5.2.1 h62dcd97_0
glob2 0.7 pyhd3eb1b0_0
google-api-core 1.25.1 pyhd3eb1b0_0
google-auth 2.12.0 pypi_0 pypi
google-auth-oauthlib 0.4.6 pypi_0 pypi
google-cloud-core 1.7.1 pyhd3eb1b0_0
google-cloud-storage 1.31.0 py_0
google-crc32c 1.1.2 py39h2bbff1b_0
google-pasta 0.2.0 pypi_0 pypi
google-resumable-media 1.3.1 pyhd3eb1b0_1
googleapis-common-protos 1.53.0 py39h2eaa2aa_0
greenlet 1.1.1 py39hd77b12b_0
grpcio 1.34.1 pypi_0 pypi
h5py 3.1.0 pypi_0 pypi
hdf5 1.10.6 h7ebc959_0
heapdict 1.0.1 pyhd3eb1b0_0
holoviews 1.14.8 pyhd3eb1b0_0
hvplot 0.7.3 pyhd3eb1b0_1
hyperlink 21.0.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
icc_rt 2019.0.0 h0cc432a_1
icu 58.2 ha925a31_3
idna 3.4 pypi_0 pypi
imagecodecs 2021.8.26 py39ha1f97ea_0
imageio 2.9.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
imagesize 1.3.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
importlib-metadata 5.0.0 pypi_0 pypi
importlib_metadata 4.11.3 hd3eb1b0_0
incremental 21.3.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
inflection 0.5.1 py39haa95532_0
iniconfig 1.1.1 pyhd3eb1b0_0
intake 0.6.5 pyhd3eb1b0_0
intel-openmp 2021.4.0 haa95532_3556
intervaltree 3.1.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
ipykernel 6.9.1 py39haa95532_0
ipython 8.2.0 py39haa95532_0
ipython_genutils 0.2.0 pyhd3eb1b0_1
ipywidgets 7.6.5 pyhd3eb1b0_1
isort 5.9.3 pyhd3eb1b0_0
itemadapter 0.3.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
itemloaders 1.0.4 pyhd3eb1b0_1
itsdangerous 2.0.1 pyhd3eb1b0_0
jdcal 1.4.1 pyhd3eb1b0_0
jedi 0.18.1 py39haa95532_1
jinja2 2.11.3 pyhd3eb1b0_0
jinja2-time 0.2.0 pyhd3eb1b0_3
jmespath 0.10.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
joblib 1.1.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
jpeg 9e h2bbff1b_0
jq 1.6 haa95532_1
json5 0.9.6 pyhd3eb1b0_0
jsonschema 4.4.0 py39haa95532_0
jupyter 1.0.0 py39haa95532_7
jupyter_client 6.1.12 pyhd3eb1b0_0
jupyter_console 6.4.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
jupyter_core 4.9.2 py39haa95532_0
jupyter_server 1.13.5 pyhd3eb1b0_0
jupyterlab 3.3.2 pyhd3eb1b0_0
jupyterlab_pygments 0.1.2 py_0
jupyterlab_server 2.10.3 pyhd3eb1b0_1
jupyterlab_widgets 1.0.0 pyhd3eb1b0_1
keras-nightly 2.5.0.dev2021032900 pypi_0 pypi
keras-preprocessing 1.1.2 pypi_0 pypi
keyring 23.4.0 py39haa95532_0
kiwisolver 1.3.2 py39hd77b12b_0
lazy-object-proxy 1.6.0 py39h2bbff1b_0
lcms2 2.12 h83e58a3_0
lerc 3.0 hd77b12b_0
libaec 1.0.4 h33f27b4_1
libarchive 3.4.2 h5e25573_0
libcrc32c 1.1.1 ha925a31_2
libcurl 7.82.0 h86230a5_0
libdeflate 1.8 h2bbff1b_5
libiconv 1.16 h2bbff1b_2
liblief 0.11.5 hd77b12b_1
libpng 1.6.37 h2a8f88b_0
libprotobuf 3.19.1 h23ce68f_0
libspatialindex 1.9.3 h6c2663c_0
libssh2 1.10.0 hcd4344a_0
libtiff 4.2.0 hd0e1b90_0
libwebp 1.2.2 h2bbff1b_0
libxml2 2.9.12 h0ad7f3c_0
libxslt 1.1.34 he774522_0
libzopfli 1.0.3 ha925a31_0
llvmlite 0.38.0 py39h23ce68f_0
locket 0.2.1 py39haa95532_2
lxml 4.8.0 py39h1985fb9_0
lz4-c 1.9.3 h2bbff1b_1
lzo 2.10 he774522_2
m2w64-libwinpthread-git 5.0.0.4634.697f757 2
markdown 3.4.1 pypi_0 pypi
matplotlib 3.5.1 py39haa95532_1
matplotlib-base 3.5.1 py39hd77b12b_1
matplotlib-inline 0.1.2 pyhd3eb1b0_2
mccabe 0.6.1 py39haa95532_1
menuinst 1.4.18 py39h59b6b97_0
mistune 0.8.4 py39h2bbff1b_1000
mkl 2021.4.0 haa95532_640
mkl-service 2.4.0 py39h2bbff1b_0
mkl_fft 1.3.1 py39h277e83a_0
mkl_random 1.2.2 py39hf11a4ad_0
mock 4.0.3 pyhd3eb1b0_0
mpmath 1.2.1 py39haa95532_0
msgpack-python 1.0.2 py39h59b6b97_1
msys2-conda-epoch 20160418 1
multidict 5.1.0 py39h2bbff1b_2
multipledispatch 0.6.0 py39haa95532_0
munkres 1.1.4 py_0
mypy_extensions 0.4.3 py39haa95532_1
navigator-updater 0.2.1 py39_1
nbclassic 0.3.5 pyhd3eb1b0_0
nbclient 0.5.13 py39haa95532_0
nbconvert 6.4.4 py39haa95532_0
nbformat 5.3.0 py39haa95532_0
nest-asyncio 1.5.5 py39haa95532_0
networkx 2.7.1 pyhd3eb1b0_0
nltk 3.4 pypi_0 pypi
nose 1.3.7 pyhd3eb1b0_1008
notebook 6.4.8 py39haa95532_0
numba 0.55.1 py39hf11a4ad_0
numexpr 2.8.1 py39hb80d3ca_0
numpy 1.19.5 pypi_0 pypi
numpy-base 1.21.5 py39hca35cd5_1
numpydoc 1.2 pyhd3eb1b0_0
oauthlib 3.2.1 pypi_0 pypi
olefile 0.46 pyhd3eb1b0_0
openjpeg 2.4.0 h4fc8c34_0
openpyxl 3.0.9 pyhd3eb1b0_0
openssl 1.1.1q h2bbff1b_0
opt-einsum 3.3.0 pypi_0 pypi
packaging 21.3 pyhd3eb1b0_0
pandas 1.4.2 py39hd77b12b_0
pandocfilters 1.5.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
panel 0.13.0 py39haa95532_0
param 1.12.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
paramiko 2.8.1 pyhd3eb1b0_0
parsel 1.6.0 py39haa95532_0
parso 0.8.3 pyhd3eb1b0_0
partd 1.2.0 pyhd3eb1b0_1
pathspec 0.7.0 py_0
patsy 0.5.2 py39haa95532_1
pep8 1.7.1 py39haa95532_0
pexpect 4.8.0 pyhd3eb1b0_3
pickleshare 0.7.5 pyhd3eb1b0_1003
pillow 9.0.1 py39hdc2b20a_0
pip 22.2.2 pypi_0 pypi
pkginfo 1.8.2 pyhd3eb1b0_0
plotly 5.6.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
pluggy 1.0.0 py39haa95532_1
powershell_shortcut 0.0.1 3
poyo 0.5.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
prometheus_client 0.13.1 pyhd3eb1b0_0
prompt-toolkit 3.0.20 pyhd3eb1b0_0
prompt_toolkit 3.0.20 hd3eb1b0_0
protego 0.1.16 py_0
protobuf 3.19.6 pypi_0 pypi
psutil 5.8.0 py39h2bbff1b_1
ptyprocess 0.7.0 pyhd3eb1b0_2
pure_eval 0.2.2 pyhd3eb1b0_0
py 1.11.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
py-lief 0.11.5 py39hd77b12b_1
pyasn1 0.4.8 pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyasn1-modules 0.2.8 pypi_0 pypi
pycodestyle 2.7.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
pycosat 0.6.3 py39h2bbff1b_0
pycparser 2.21 pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyct 0.4.6 py39haa95532_0
pycurl 7.44.1 py39hcd4344a_1
pydispatcher 2.0.5 py39haa95532_2
pydocstyle 6.1.1 pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyerfa 2.0.0 py39h2bbff1b_0
pyflakes 2.3.1 pyhd3eb1b0_0
pygments 2.11.2 pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyhamcrest 2.0.2 pyhd3eb1b0_2
pyjwt 2.1.0 py39haa95532_0
pylint 2.9.6 py39haa95532_1
pyls-spyder 0.4.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
pynacl 1.4.0 py39hbd8134f_1
pyodbc 4.0.32 py39hd77b12b_1
pyopenssl 21.0.0 pyhd3eb1b0_1
pyparsing 3.0.4 pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyqt 5.9.2 py39hd77b12b_6
pyreadline 2.1 py39haa95532_1
pyrsistent 0.18.0 py39h196d8e1_0
pysocks 1.7.1 py39haa95532_0
pytables 3.6.1 py39h56d22b6_1
pytest 7.1.1 py39haa95532_0
python 3.9.12 h6244533_0
python-dateutil 2.8.2 pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-fastjsonschema 2.15.1 pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-levenshtein 0.12.2 pypi_0 pypi
python-libarchive-c 2.9 pyhd3eb1b0_1
python-lsp-black 1.0.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-lsp-jsonrpc 1.0.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-lsp-server 1.2.4 pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-slugify 5.0.2 pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-snappy 0.6.0 py39hd77b12b_3
pytz 2021.3 pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyviz_comms 2.0.2 pyhd3eb1b0_0
pywavelets 1.3.0 py39h2bbff1b_0
pywin32 302 py39h2bbff1b_2
pywin32-ctypes 0.2.0 py39haa95532_1000
pywinpty 2.0.2 py39h5da7b33_0
pyyaml 6.0 py39h2bbff1b_1
pyzmq 22.3.0 py39hd77b12b_2
qdarkstyle 3.0.2 pyhd3eb1b0_0
qstylizer 0.1.10 pyhd3eb1b0_0
qt 5.9.7 vc14h73c81de_0
qtawesome 1.0.3 pyhd3eb1b0_0
qtconsole 5.3.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
qtpy 2.0.1 pyhd3eb1b0_0
queuelib 1.5.0 py39haa95532_0
regex 2022.3.15 py39h2bbff1b_0
requests 2.28.1 pypi_0 pypi
requests-file 1.5.1 pyhd3eb1b0_0
requests-oauthlib 1.3.1 pypi_0 pypi
rope 0.22.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
rsa 4.9 pypi_0 pypi
rtree 0.9.7 py39h2eaa2aa_1
ruamel_yaml 0.15.100 py39h2bbff1b_0
s3transfer 0.5.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
scikit-image 0.19.2 py39hf11a4ad_0
scikit-learn 1.0.2 py39hf11a4ad_1
scikit-learn-intelex 2021.5.0 py39haa95532_0
scipy 1.7.3 py39h0a974cb_0
scrapy 2.6.1 py39haa95532_0
seaborn 0.11.2 pyhd3eb1b0_0
send2trash 1.8.0 pyhd3eb1b0_1
service_identity 18.1.0 pyhd3eb1b0_1
setuptools 65.4.1 pypi_0 pypi
singledispatch 3.7.0 pypi_0 pypi
sip 4.19.13 py39hd77b12b_0
six 1.15.0 pypi_0 pypi
smart_open 5.1.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
snappy 1.1.9 h6c2663c_0
sniffio 1.2.0 py39haa95532_1
snowballstemmer 2.2.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
sortedcollections 2.1.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
sortedcontainers 2.4.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
soupsieve 2.3.1 pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinx 4.4.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-applehelp 1.0.2 pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-devhelp 1.0.2 pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp 2.0.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-jsmath 1.0.1 pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-qthelp 1.0.3 pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.5 pyhd3eb1b0_0
spyder 5.1.5 py39haa95532_1
spyder-kernels 2.1.3 py39haa95532_0
sqlalchemy 1.4.32 py39h2bbff1b_0
sqlite 3.38.2 h2bbff1b_0
stack_data 0.2.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
statsmodels 0.13.2 py39h2bbff1b_0
sympy 1.10.1 py39haa95532_0
tabulate 0.8.9 py39haa95532_0
tbb 2021.5.0 h59b6b97_0
tbb4py 2021.5.0 py39h59b6b97_0
tblib 1.7.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
tenacity 8.0.1 py39haa95532_0
tensorboard 2.10.1 pypi_0 pypi
tensorboard-data-server 0.6.1 pypi_0 pypi
tensorboard-plugin-wit 1.8.1 pypi_0 pypi
tensorflow 2.5.0 pypi_0 pypi
tensorflow-estimator 2.5.0 pypi_0 pypi
termcolor 1.1.0 pypi_0 pypi
terminado 0.13.1 py39haa95532_0
testpath 0.5.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
text-unidecode 1.3 pyhd3eb1b0_0
textdistance 4.2.1 pyhd3eb1b0_0
threadpoolctl 2.2.0 pyh0d69192_0
three-merge 0.1.1 pyhd3eb1b0_0
tifffile 2021.7.2 pyhd3eb1b0_2
tinycss 0.4 pyhd3eb1b0_1002
tk 8.6.11 h2bbff1b_0
tldextract 3.2.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
toml 0.10.2 pyhd3eb1b0_0
tomli 1.2.2 pyhd3eb1b0_0
toolz 0.11.2 pyhd3eb1b0_0
tornado 6.1 py39h2bbff1b_0
tqdm 4.64.0 py39haa95532_0
traitlets 5.1.1 pyhd3eb1b0_0
twisted 22.2.0 py39h2bbff1b_0
twisted-iocpsupport 1.0.2 py39h2bbff1b_0
typed-ast 1.4.3 py39h2bbff1b_1
typing-extensions 3.7.4.3 pypi_0 pypi
typing_extensions 4.1.1 pyh06a4308_0
tzdata 2022a hda174b7_0
ujson 5.1.0 py39hd77b12b_0
unidecode 1.2.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
urllib3 1.26.12 pypi_0 pypi
vc 14.2 h21ff451_1
vs2015_runtime 14.27.29016 h5e58377_2
w3lib 1.21.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
watchdog 2.1.6 py39haa95532_0
wcwidth 0.2.5 pyhd3eb1b0_0
webencodings 0.5.1 py39haa95532_1
websocket-client 0.58.0 py39haa95532_4
werkzeug 2.2.2 pypi_0 pypi
wheel 0.37.1 pypi_0 pypi
widgetsnbextension 3.5.2 py39haa95532_0
win_inet_pton 1.1.0 py39haa95532_0
win_unicode_console 0.5 py39haa95532_0
wincertstore 0.2 py39haa95532_2
winpty 0.4.3 4
wrapt 1.12.1 py39h196d8e1_1
xarray 0.20.1 pyhd3eb1b0_1
xgboost 1.6.2 pypi_0 pypi
xlrd 2.0.1 pyhd3eb1b0_0
xlsxwriter 3.0.3 pyhd3eb1b0_0
xlwings 0.24.9 py39haa95532_0
xz 5.2.5 h62dcd97_0
yaml 0.2.5 he774522_0
yapf 0.31.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
yarl 1.6.3 py39h2bbff1b_0
zfp 0.5.5 hd77b12b_6
zict 2.0.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0
zipp 3.9.0 pypi_0 pypi
zlib 1.2.12 h8cc25b3_2
zope 1.0 py39haa95532_1
zope.interface 5.4.0 py39h2bbff1b_0
zstd 1.4.9 h19a0ad4_0
```

Pip list:

```
ansi2html 1.8.0
arrow 1.2.3
asttokens 2.0.8
attrs 22.1.0
aws-lambda-builders 1.19.0
aws-sam-cli 1.59.0
aws-sam-translator 1.52.0
backcall 0.2.0
backports.zoneinfo 0.2.1
binaryornot 0.4.4
boto3 1.24.89
botocore 1.27.89
Brotli 1.0.9
category-encoders 2.5.1.post0
certifi 2020.11.8
chardet 3.0.4
charset-normalizer 2.1.1
chevron 0.14.0
chromedriver-py 81.0.4044.69
click 8.1.3
colorama 0.4.3
contourpy 1.0.5
cookiecutter 2.1.1
cycler 0.11.0
Cython 3.0.0a11
darkdetect 0.1.1
dash 2.6.2
dash-core-components 2.0.0
dash-html-components 2.0.0
dash-table 5.0.0
dateparser 1.1.1
debugpy 1.6.3
decorator 5.1.1
Deprecated 1.2.13
docker 4.2.2
entrypoints 0.4
executing 1.1.1
Flask 2.2.2
Flask-Compress 1.13
Flask-Cors 3.0.10
fonttools 4.37.4
idna 2.10
imbalanced-learn 0.9.1
importlib-metadata 5.0.0
ipykernel 6.16.0
ipython 8.5.0
ipywidgets 8.0.2
itsdangerous 2.1.2
jedi 0.18.1
Jinja2 3.1.2
jinja2-time 0.2.0
jmespath 0.10.0
joblib 1.2.0
Js2Py 0.68
jsonschema 3.2.0
jupyter_client 7.3.5
jupyter_core 5.0.0rc1
jupyter-dash 0.4.2
jupyterlab-widgets 3.0.3
kaleido 0.2.1
kiwisolver 1.4.4
lightgbm 3.3.2
llvmlite 0.38.1
lxml 4.5.0
MarkupSafe 2.0.1
matplotlib 3.6.1
matplotlib-inline 0.1.6
nest-asyncio 1.5.6
nltk 3.4
numba 0.55.2
numpy 1.22.4
orjson 3.8.0
packaging 21.3
pandas 1.4.4
parso 0.8.3
patsy 0.5.2
pickleshare 0.7.5
Pillow 9.2.0
pip 22.2.2
platformdirs 2.5.2
plotly 5.10.0
plotly-resampler 0.8.2rc3
pmdarima 1.8.5
prompt-toolkit 3.0.31
psutil 5.9.2
pure-eval 0.2.2
pycaret 3.0.0rc4
pycryptodomex 3.9.9
Pygments 2.13.0
pyjsparser 2.7.1
pyod 1.0.5
pyparsing 3.0.9
pypiwin32 223
PyQt5 5.14.2
PyQt5-sip 12.8.1
pyrsistent 0.18.1
python-dateutil 2.8.2
python-Levenshtein 0.12.2
python-slugify 6.1.2
pytz 2020.4
pywin32 304
PyYAML 5.4.1
pyzmq 24.0.1
regex 2021.9.30
requests 2.28.1
retrying 1.3.3
s3transfer 0.6.0
schemdraw 0.15
scikit-learn 1.1.2
scikit-plot 0.3.7
scipy 1.8.1
selenium 3.141.0
serverlessrepo 0.1.10
setuptools 41.2.0
singledispatch 3.7.0
six 1.15.0
sktime 0.13.4
stack-data 0.5.1
statsmodels 0.13.2
tbats 1.1.1
tenacity 8.1.0
text-unidecode 1.3
threadpoolctl 3.1.0
tomlkit 0.7.2
tornado 6.2
tqdm 4.64.1
trace-updater 0.0.8
traitlets 5.4.0
typing-extensions 3.10.0.0
tzdata 2022.4
tzlocal 3.0
urllib3 1.25.11
watchdog 2.1.2
wcwidth 0.2.5
websocket-client 1.4.1
Werkzeug 2.2.2
wheel 0.37.1
widgetsnbextension 4.0.3
wrapt 1.14.1
yellowbrick 1.5
zipp 3.9.0
zmq 0.0.0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: cannot import name 'soft\_unicode' from 'markupsafe'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72191560/importerror-cannot-import-name-soft-unicode-from-markupsafe) - a google of "markupsafe soft_unicode" would have lead you right to this answer, as that's all I did to find it.

Comment: Yes I tried to run pip install markupsafe==2.0.1 and still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please type `pip freeze` to check which is your current markupsafe version?

Comment: it says : MarkupSafe==2.0.1