# Getting an Error and Cant open my jupyter notebook

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 41, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from jinja2.environment import Environment, Template
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 15, in <module>
    from jinja2 import nodes
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\nodes.py", line 19, in <module>
    from jinja2.utils import Markup
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\utils.py", line 647, in <module>
    from markupsafe import Markup, escape, soft_unicode
ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe' (C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\markupsafe\__init__.py)
```

i was doing the project Sign language Detection from NICHOLAS RENOTTE i was getting a lot errors somehow i managaed some of them and got stuck in creating TF record file and i was refering some suggestions from Stack itself and i closed the anaconda and jupyter notebook also and i opened freshly and im unable open it

someone please help to go through this project

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: cannot import name 'soft\_unicode' from 'markupsafe'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72191560/importerror-cannot-import-name-soft-unicode-from-markupsafe)